# Rename-Computer is throwing "access is denied" error but I can't figure out to what

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I am on a Windows 10 Enterprise machine that is hosting hyperv machines. We will call this "Win10Host".
One of the virtual machines is "Win10Base" which is a base install of Windows 10 Pro.

I am attempting to run the below from "Win10Host" to rename "Win10Base" and it is failing (errors below).

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString 'mypassword' -AsPlainText -Force
$localCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('user', $secpasswd);

$computername = 'Win10Base';
$VMName = 'Win10BaseNew';
$VMIP = 'x.x.x.x';  //Redacted, I have used remote desktop to verify this ip is correct.

Rename-Computer -ComputerName $VMIP -LocalCredential $localCreds -NewName $VMName -Verbose;
```

Win10Base is a basic click through windows 10 pro install.
user is the initial user setup after install.

### At first it was throwing:

```
Rename-Computer : Cannot establish the WMI connection to the computer 'Win10Base' 
with the following error message: Access denied .
At line:9 char:1
+ Rename-Computer -ComputerName $computername -LocalCredential $localCr ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Win10Base:String) [Rename-Computer], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameComputerException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameComputerCommand
```

After giving permissions to Remote Desktop, configuring the firewall, giving permissions to "Windows Management Instrumentation" in dcomcnfg, and giving access through wmimgmt.msc to the CIMV2 namespace I have arrived at my current situation.

### Currently the powershell throws:

```
Rename-Computer : Fail to rename computer 'Win10Base' to 'Win10BaseNew' 
due to the following exception: Access is denied.
At line:9 char:1
+ Rename-Computer -ComputerName $computername -LocalCredential $localCr ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Win10Base:String) [Rename-Computer], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailToRenameComputer,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameComputerCommand
```

### Run scenarios:

On Win10Base ISE - fails with the "access denied".

On Win10Base ISE run as admin - success.

On Win10Host ISE - fails with the "access denied"

On Win10Host ISE run as admin - fails with the "access denied"

As best I can tell user on Win10Base is an administrator.  I even enabled "god mode" to see if I could change the user type to a high level and found it was in the administrators group.

Checking Windows Event logs (Application, Security, Setup, and system) I see nothing to correlate with the current access denied.  Nothing is picked up in DbView as best I can tell.

**So any suggestions on where to look next for WHAT access is denied would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: So WMI and DCOM are "fun", but why not just try `Invoke-Command` to remote to the machine and perform the `Rename-Computer` locally? (If the VMs are supposed to be joined to the domain this will get more complicated as you'd need to remote a domain credential.) In general you'll want to use PowerShell remoting where at all possible, since it's the most hassle-free way of remote administration compared to the alternatives. (Setting up remoting to VMs may be a little trickier than regular machines if you have to work with IP addresses, but that would still be worthwhile.)

Comment: If the machine isn't on the domain your user domain needs to be specified in credentials - DOMAIN\user - where the domain is the local machine name. Also enable WinRM in the remote machine using "winrm quickconfig" at command line

Comment: @Scepticalist Enabling Windows Remote Management and setting HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
key:LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy  to equal 1

Was the missing piece and Resolved this issue.  Please come post that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the machine isn't on the domain your user domain needs to be specified in credentials - DOMAIN\user - where the domain is the local machine name.

Also enable WinRM in the remote machine using "winrm quickconfig" at command line

Comment: Turns out Windows Remote Management service is off by default for Windows 10 Pro.  Turning it on resolved the final access denied.